# Unable to import storage from google.cloud

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, jupyter-notebook, google-cloud-datalab

I'm new to Google Cloud Platform, and have uploaded some machine learning code on Jupyter notebook in DataLab.

My issue is although, I installed Google Cloud Storage (using the command: `pip install --upgrade google-cloud-storage`), I'm unable to import this.

The following is how I'm importing this package:

```
>>import numpy    
>>import pandas as pd   
>>from google.cloud import storage
```

But I'm getting the following error:

> ImportErrorTraceback (most recent call last)
>    in ()
>   ----> 1 from google.cloud import storage
>
> ImportError: cannot import name storage

Note:

1. This is the content of my JSON config file: `{"TokenSources":["env"]}`
2. I tried `export GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS="/path/to/file.json"`, but the error persists.
3. I verified that this package is indeed installed in my environment by typing pip freeze in the command shell:

   ---

google-cloud==0.34.0

google-cloud-datastore==1.7.0

google-cloud-spanner==1.4.0

google-cloud-storage==1.10.0

---

What am I missing here?

Comment: Can you try uninstalling and reinstalling again ?(Some people reported this fixed their issue [here](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-python/issues/2464) although it was 2016, but it is worth a shot IMO) 
> I had to uninstall both google-cloud and also protobuf, then let google-cloud reinstall protobuf.

Comment: I'll give this a shot and convey the outcome. Thanks for your response.

Answer (score 3):

Have you installed the `google-cloud-storage` package in your DataLab environment, or on your local machine? You'll need to run the following command within DataLab:

```
!pip install google-cloud-storage
```

See https://cloud.google.com/datalab/docs/how-to/adding-libraries for more details

Also, the `google-cloud` package is deprecated, you shouldn't need to install it, see https://pypi.org/project/google-cloud/.

Comment: I did run the pip install within DataLab. But thanks for your response.

Comment: It's possible that the existence of the deprecated `google-cloud` package is somehow interfering, can you remove it, reinstall `google-cloud-storage` and confirm that it's still not working?

Answer (score 2):

So I got it working upon importing storage as follows:

> > import google.datalab.storage as storage

Answer (score 1):

To make your notebooks resilient to both datalab and non-datalab environments you can use one of the the following methods for handling your import statements:

```py
try:
  from google.cloud import storage
except ImportError:
  from google.datalab import storage
```

or

```py
if 'google.datalab' in sys.modules:
  from google.datalab import storage
else:
  from google.cloud import storage
```

---

Alternatively if you would like to switch datalab to using  `from google.cloud import storage`

Run the following in a cell

```py
!pip install google-cloud-storage
```

Followed by this cell to reset the IPython kernel

```py
# Reset the IPython kernel
from IPython.core.display import HTML
HTML("<script>Jupyter.notebook.kernel.restart()</script>")
```

**Note**: You need to reset the Python kernel after installation otherwise you will a `ContextualVersionConflict` error from naming conflicts